# At which "level" is multi-threading most effective?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm

Forgive me for my use of the word "level" but I am not sure what else to call it. I am writing a game engine. This game engine loads a number of files required for operation. These files are mostly archives and they contain numerous files within them. The files are individually broken into zlib compressed blocks.

My question is at which level I should implement the multithreading?

For the sake of argument let's say:

15 archive files (10mb each)

20 files in each archive (0.5mb)

Each file is made up of hundreds of compressed blocks.

I realize that if I did it at the block inflation level, it would evenly distribute the tasks and there would be no bottlebneck if there was a very large file. But I run the risk of creating too many thread.

Edit: I should clarify that I understand multithreading I/O from a disk doesn't help too much. For my question, I am mainly asking about the processing and parsing of these files at different levels. Imagine that the I/O is already handled and I am just worrying about parsing these files.

Comment: 10mb of data? How long does it take to process these without multi-threading?

Comment: Don't create more threads than available cores, that would be counterproductive.

Comment: As @Lucas Trzesniewski said above, no more threads than available cores.  Think of your problem in terms of "tasks" (e.g. things to do) and worker threads that can be assigned "tasks".  Keep the thread complexity to a minimum bearing in mind that the more things that are logically parallel the harder it is to properly test the code.  First ask yourself - what is the benefit of threading and how much are things really impacted if I do without it.

Comment: Try all three versions (exclusively archives or blocks as well both at the same time) and measure the result. Personally, I'd go for blocks if at all possible, as it seems like it would be the one that scaled more elegantly (depending on details ofc).

Comment: *"But I run the risk of creating too many thread."* - a *thread pool* can remove that particular risk, but if the work is excessively fine-grained you'll still have unnecessary overheads.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is I/O bound to a single disk drive, then it might be counter productive to multithread. You need to figure out how much time your program takes for reading the files and how much time it takes to processing the data.

If most of the time is used for data reading from the disk, then multithreading won't help you that much.

If a large part of the time is used for data processing, then 1 thread per core is a good rule of thumb, but you should leave the reading part to a single thread, and the processing part to your pool of 1 thread per code (i.e. Single-Producer-Multiple-Consumers design).

Comment: Was going to mention this answer in a comment since OP talked about developing a game engine .. I know many a consumer grade laptop that do not have the best (or most defragmeneted) hard drives.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about multithreading the actual I/O input. This would only take into account the parsing and processing of these files.

Comment: Either way, my answer stands. Single producer to read the data, a thread pool to process it. Thread pool size = core count.

Comment: @txtechhelp Actually multithreading reading different files from a fragmented drive may be a good idea if you have spinning disks. If you queue up 8 requests, the drive can figure out if there's a faster way to provide them than reading one-by-one. Then again, in this case (10mb) it's unlikely to matter these days.

Answer (score 2):

When your units of work are too big/coarse you might not saturate all CPUs or when processing the last items some CPUs might be idle waiting for slow items to be completed.

When the units of work are too small the overhead of distributing the work and merging results is too big.

Usually, the fastest approach is to use the smallest size/level that is acceptable from an overhead standpoint.

Architecturally, doing parallelism at a higher level is often easier because you automatically parallelize the entire subtree of the call graph in one go.

These are the trade-offs. You need to decide yourself for your particular case. It sounds like parallelizing at the file level is the right approach here. It gives you 15*20=300 work items to spread across like 4-8 cores typically. That's a good distribution ratio.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, don't run more threads than you have logical cpus. You can't go faster and you just introduce overhead.

Unless you have some specific situation that requires more specialised handling, I'd suggest to just create a threadpool (with executors == number of cpus), then create a runner/scheduler for each situation - one to schedule an archive as a job, then a file as a job. Go with the better performing solution.

Without knowing exactly what your code looks like, I doubt you can get a more clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, your are asking if you should use threads for each archive files, or each files in archives, or even lower?

If that is it i do not think we can give you an answer. Firstly, do you need to multi-threading? The number you gave are not impressive, it looks like it should run fast enough with only one thread.

If not, i would advise you to implement the simplest level of multi-threading, the top level (so for each archive files) and again see if you need more performance.

If yes, implement the other levels and measure. Too many different factors to know beforehand. If not, you can go work on something else :-)